# Auto show rest of TextView

Tags: android, textview

How to make single line `TextView` appears if the screen small?, Because it's makes 3 dots of `ellipsize` without defining it in `XML` and the rest of text disappeared.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: use a smaller font size for a small screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add:

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

OR

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

to your TextView

EDIT:

Your TextView can look something like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/your_text"
        android:maxLines = "1"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"/>
```

and add these two lines to your `onCreate`

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Not too clean but does the job.

SECOND EDIT:

```
   <TextView
        android:text="@string/yourText"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"  <!-- Please change according to requirement -->
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need it to be single line.

Comment: You would unfortunately have to use a smaller font size for the text and try using as much as the screen (width wise) as possible

Comment: Actually, I see a way around. You can make the text scrollable. Ill edit the post in a bit with the code for you to try out

Comment: Also, add `yourTextView.setSelected(true);` in your java

Comment: Didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post your TextView xml ?